# SQL distinctly arranging column query issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following table:

**dbPratiche :**

[image]

In this i wanted to arrage distinct [Provincia contraente] (first column) and count of that [Provincia contraente] present in [Provincia Agenzia].

Eg.

If I arrange fist column in distinct with following query:

```
select distinct([Provincia contraente]) from dbPratiche
```

Then wanted to give count in next column how many times it has arrived in second column i.e.[Provincia Agenzia]

In simple words, prototypal query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( [provincia contraente] ), 
               Count([provincia agenzia]) 
FROM   dbpratiche 
WHERE  Distinct([provincia contraente]) = [provincia agenzia]
```

Ofcourse this query fails, but i made second query with joins as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( p1.[provincia contraente] ) AS 'PC', 
               Count(p2.[provincia agenzia]) 
FROM   dbpratiche p1 
       INNER JOIN dbpratiche p2 
               ON p1.[provincia contraente] = p2.[provincia contraente] 
                  AND p2.[provincia agenzia] = p1.[provincia contraente] 
GROUP  BY p1.[provincia contraente]
```

But not giving me correct results.

Please help me.

Actual table:

```
Provincia contraente  |  Provincia Agenzia

TA                          TA

CE                          TA

CE                          CE

MI                          FR

MI                          TA

FR                          FR
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Provincia contraente  |  Provincia Agenzia

TA                          3

CE                          1

MI                          0

FR                          2
```

**EDIT2:**

Also wanted to add count of first column

```
Provincia contraente  |  Provincia Agenzia  | cnt Provincia contraente

TA                          3                      1

CE                          1                      2

MI                          0                      2

FR                          2                      1
```

I tried:

I added `COUNT(dbPratiche.[Provincia contraente])` in @verex's query as

```
SELECT T1.[provincia contraente], 
       Count(dbpratiche.[provincia agenzia]), 
       Count(dbpratiche.[provincia contraente]) 
FROM   dbpratiche 
       RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [provincia contraente] 
                   FROM   dbpratiche) AS T1 
               ON dbpratiche.[provincia agenzia] = T1.[provincia contraente] 
GROUP  BY T1.[provincia contraente]
```

But got the count of [Provincia Agenzia]

plz help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query also shows 0 values:

```
SELECT [provincia contraente], 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN [provincia contraente] = [provincia agenzia] THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
           END) 
FROM   dbpratiche 
GROUP  BY [provincia contraente]
```

**UPD:** Here is the query which works for updated question:

```
SELECT T1.[provincia contraente], 
       Count(dbpratiche.[provincia agenzia]), 
       Max(T1.cnt) 
FROM   dbpratiche 
       RIGHT JOIN (SELECT [provincia contraente], 
                          Count(*) AS Cnt 
                   FROM   dbpratiche 
                   GROUP  BY [provincia contraente]) AS T1 
               ON dbpratiche.[provincia agenzia] = T1.[provincia contraente] 
GROUP  BY T1.[provincia contraente]
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/226ff/7)</kbd>

Comment: @LOLSinger: I've changed query. [See sqlfiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/226ff/7)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to,use a group by statement.

```
select  [Provincia contraente],count([Provincia Agenzia])
from dbPratiche where [Provincia contraente]=[Provincia Agenzia]
group by [Provincia contraente]
```

Comment: Could you update your question to indicate what the desired results are.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `distinct` here. The grouping already gets you unique values for the grouped column.

Try this one

```
 select [Provincia contraente], count([Provincia Agenzia])
 from dbPratiche 
 where [Provincia contraente] = [Provincia Agenzia]
 group by [Provincia contraente]
```

Comment: Forgot to remove it. Check now.